Error "DLL load failed while importing inline_ext: The specified module could not be found"
Consider:
def load_cuda(cuda_src, cpp_src, funcs, opt=False, verbose=False):
    return load_inline(cuda_sources=[cuda_src], cpp_sources=[cpp_src], functions=funcs, extra_cuda_cflags=["-O2"] if opt else [], verbose=verbose,name="inline_ext")

module = load_cuda(cuda_src, cpp_src, ['rgb_to_grayscale'], verbose=True)

This error is showing:

DLL load failed while importing inline_ext: The specified module could not be found.

I installed ninja CUDA and others needed. How can I fix this problem?
I tried all the versions, yet it is not working. My CUDA version is 12.1. Python interpreter: the latest

Is there enough information to answer the question?
